# Finding the number of combinations

Tags: combinatorics

Some boxes are labeled as $4,3,5,9,6$. A box with label $x$ gives a random integer $n$ such that, $1\leq n\leq x$. Thus we can get a collection of five numbers by each box. One such collection is $4,2,1,2,6$. Two collections are same if one is a permutation of other. So $1,2,1,1,6$ is same as $2,1,1,1,6$. Now we have to calculate the total number of different collections we can get by repeatedly performing this act.

Can someone please help me out with this question??

Comment: Please share your own attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: I tried to write the code for this in C++ using next_permutation and is_permutation but I was unable to because for 8-9 boxes a brute force approach would have been too slow.  Then i tried to solve it on paper and I was unable to so.... I posted the question here .

Comment: Creating cases would help

Comment: I created a few case for analysing like  (1,2,3) The answer came out as 5.